If cell is blank copy the next 14 adjacent cell in column in row "a"
I am trying to select the first 14 in Row A which are adjacent to a blank cell within Row C
Public Sub filterBlanks()
  With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
      .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
  End With
End Sub

I got this far but can't manage to get the selection of the 14 first appearing next blank, would appreciate any help.
I am trying to create a macro which can copy the first 14 adjacent numbers, in row "A" that appear next to a blank cell, in row "C".

in row "A" that appear next to a blank cell, in row "C". Do you mean Col A / C or Row1 / Row 3?
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

please see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and read How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? and don't forget to read Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question? . Also check out the tour, and help center

I figured it out.
Sub CopyNumbers()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim rngBlank As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the source worksheet
    Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Open the target workbook
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("I:\My Drive\gs1 number my numbers - test.xlsx")
    
    ' Find the first blank cell in column C of the target workbook
    For i = 1 To wbTarget.Sheets(1).Cells(wbTarget.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        If IsEmpty(wbTarget.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "C")) Then
            Set rngBlank = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "C")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Check if a blank cell was found
    If rngBlank Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No blank cell found in column C of the target workbook.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Copy the corresponding cell and the 13 cells below from column A of the target workbook
    Set rngTarget = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range(wbTarget.Sheets(1).Cells(rngBlank.Row, "A"), wbTarget.Sheets(1).Cells(rngBlank.Row + 13, "A"))
    
    ' Paste the copied values to cell E5:E18 of the active worksheet
    wsSource.Range("E5").Resize(14, 1).Value = rngTarget.Value
End Sub


Did you consider working with this formula:
=LEN(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;C1:C14))

It takes all cell values from cells "C1" up to "C14" and concatenates them without delimiter. After that, the length is taken. From the moment the length equals zero, it means that all cells from "C1" up to "C14" are empty.
As I'm working here with relative cell references ("C1:C14"), dragging this formula to the next row turns this into =LEN(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;C2:C15)) and further.
Putting this formula in a helper column can give you the information you need.
